# How to convert string to Date object without time and timezone information in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm trying to make a plot using d3.js. The data is passing from server.js to index.js. The raw date column has the format of "December 03, 2023" and I want to convert it to 2023-12-03 so I can use it with a plot function I have written. I was able to achieve this with

```
fetchData.forEach(item => {
        console.log(item.date_added)
        parsedDate = new Date(item.date_added);
        item.date_added = parsedDate.getFullYear() + '-' +
                    ('0' + (parsedDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
                    ('0' + parsedDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    })
```

However, this return a string type and I need it to be a Date object. Using `item.date_added = new Date(item.date_added);` reverts it back to the origin form with the extract time and timezone.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/m3jco1te/

Comment: Always fascinated by those who want to parse a string to a date, then extract parts of the date to construct a string again. All you need to do is break the inital string into its parts, convert the month name to a number, then arrange the parts as needed. It avoids parsing the timestamp to a date and the vagaries involved. If you really need to go via *Date*, use a library to parse the string and format the date so you supply both formats to ensure it's parsed and formatted correctly and reliably, e.g. using moment.js: `moment(timestamp, 'MMMM DD, YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))`.